# Is there a way to scan a file and ignore int variables while storing strings?

Tags: java, arrays, string, int, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to scan a text file and store the strings into an array while ignoring the first line. When I run the code it has a blank spot and the array is missing a string. Is there anyway to scan the file and have it skip over the int value and include all the strings?

File file = new File("input.txt");

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);



    int size = scan.nextInt();

    String[] blocks = new String[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {

        blocks[i] = scan.nextLine();

    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(blocks));
```

[, MXTUAS, OQATGE, REWMNA, MBDFAC]

Comment: Look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading the entire line each time, including for the initial integer value:

```
File file = new File("input.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

int size = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
String[] blocks = new String[size];

for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    blocks[i] = scan.nextLine();
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(blocks));
```

Comment: Sorry can you explain why only changing "scan.nextInt;" made it work? Whats the difference between that and  "Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());"

Comment: I'm not an expert in the `Scanner` API, but it has to do with that `Scanner#nextInt()` might not consume the newline which appears after the number.  So, that value then falls over to the next (first) call to `Scanner#nextLine`.